# Basic iPhone app development issue regarding basic UI

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I have a basic question regarding iOS development. I have created view file ViewController.xib. I do have ViewController.h file. The xib file contains components, such as text field, stepper and so on. When I run the iPhone app the window is empty. I know that I need to drag and drop components from xib file to ViewController.h file in order to make properties, but this is what I cannot achieve. I drag the items them self but there supposed to be a  pointer arrow being dragged up.
As far as I can recall I need to perform some other things even before this operation by dragging files somewhere. So, can someone tell me what needs to be done, please.
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your .xib is loading properly, then any controls in the view should be visible, they just won't function if they aren't 'wired' into your class.  It sounds like you're just setting out on iPhone development, I would recommend you look at Ray Wenderlich's Storyboard tutorial - this takes you through creating a basic app, and creating the view hierarchy: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Basically .xib file is a design template.Which is associated with a viewcontroller.h and viewcontroller.m files. You can place controls by dragging from the objects section from the right pane.These controls will be created automatically at runtime.To address these controls you need to make connection between them and the control variables you declare in your viewcontroller.h file.Even if you are not making connections , the controls will be visible and functional but u cannot control them, because you dont have it connected to an object reference